# Can't import css

Tags: css

I'm trying to import a CSS file into another CSS file, but no matter how I define the path the file won't load, any suggestions to why?

[image]

Comment: Check Your import path, which is differ in live than your editor

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `@import` rule needs to be the first rules in your file. Put your imports at the start of the file and it works.

Your `@import`s must come before all other content in your CSS. And I mean all of your content. Even putting comments before the `@import` tag will cause your imports to fail. So be sure to do your imports before you do anything else.

Comment: Reference: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#at-import (comments before it shouldn't be an issue though)

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the @import in the starting of your file like this.

```
@import url('loader.css');
/* rest CSS code */
```

Hope it helps

Cheers